# How to add $filter to OData aggregation binding in XML

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm using UploadCollection to upload Attachments in a SAPUI5 App.

InstantUpload is true.

After Upload, I want to show the uploaded Attachment in the UploadCollection-Control.

Therefore, when Upload is completed, I refresh the Model.

This calls the GET_ENTITYSET method in backend, but I need to provide a TimeStamp, which is in String format.

My UploadCollection-Control has the following attribute:

```
items="{path: '/Products?$filter=Timestamp eq 'TestString' '}"
```

But this doesn`t work.

I tried

```
items="{path: '/Products?$filter=Timestamp eq ''TestString'' '}"
```

and this either didn´t work.

IV_FILTER_STRING and IT_FILTER_SELECT_OPTIONS is empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter UI5 aggregation binding in XML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981824/filter-ui5-aggregation-binding-in-xml-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for something like **SAPUI5 binding filter in XML view** you find x Stack Overflow entries.

Here's your solution:

```
items="{
  path: '/Products',
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'Timestamp',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: 'TestString'
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: Thank you, works.
How do I use value1 with binding?
value1: '{Timestamp}' doesn't work

Comment: @Topper See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41782480/5846045